# Getting BCNF from a group of functional dependencies

Tags: database, bcnf

Here is a group of FDs(3NF):

A-> BDEFG

CF->A

BG->C

How can I decompose this relation to BCNF?

I guess there are still dependencies in CF->A because A->F, but have no idea how to decompose it..

Anyone can help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For FD 1 and FD 2, you can see that A and CF are both keys of this relation and these FDs do not violate BCNF. For FD 3, BG is not the key so you need to decompose into : {B G C} AND { B G A D E F} according to the decomposing algorithm. Now it's done since {B G C} corresponds to FD 3 and { B G A D E F} satisfies with FD 1. Hope this helps.